# Are C++ Constructor delegates already available in VS2008?

Tags: delegates, standards, c++11

I cant seem to find any useful information whether constructor delegates that are proposed for C++0x are already available in Visual Studio 2008 / 2010. I tried to use them and got pretty strange errors, but I can't test this in VS2010 currently. Can anyone tell me if they are available already?

cheers,

Tom

Comment: [This](http://wiki.apache.org/stdcxx/C++0xCompilerSupport) might be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They aren't available yet.

:(